# HTML emails using Swift "quoted" in Gmail

Tags: php, email, gmail, html-email, swiftmailer

I am sending a *very* simple HTML email (it's mainly just a happy holidays image, centered) from my site using Swift.

It works perfectly in several clients (Thunderbird, Outlook Express, Yahoo Mail), but for some reason Gmail considers it as 'quoted content' and therefore the user does not see any of it unless they click the tiny '- Show quoted content -' link in the email.

This obviously does not work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not to derail the conversation but I like how the word quoted is quoted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is the message with the image inside of a conversation? Often, when I send multiple test messages to my gmail account, it will show them as quoted in the conversation stack. Try sending it to a different gmail account and see if it happens again.

Comment: That was it. I feel like a moron. Learn something new everyday. :) Thanks a lot. Merry Christmas.